# Is it correct to say that there is no implied ordering in the presentation of grammar options in the C++ Standard?

Tags: c++, parsing, language-lawyer

I'll try to explain my question with an example. Consider the following grammar production in the C++ standard:

> [*literal*](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.literal#nt:literal):
>      *integer-literal*
>      *character-literal*
>      *floating-point-literal*
>      *string-literal*
>      *boolean-literal*
>      *pointer-literal*
>      *user-defined-literal*

Once the parser identifies a *literal* as an *integer-literal*, I always thought that the parser would just stop there. But I was told that this is **not** true. The parser will continue parsing to verify whether the *literal* could also be matched with a *user-defined-literal*, for example.

Is this correct?

**Edit**

I decided to include this edit as my interpretation of the Standard, in response to @rici's excellent answer below, although with a result that is the opposite of the one advocated by the OP.

One can read the following in [stmt.ambig]/1 and /3 (emphases are mine):

[[stmt.ambig]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ambig#1)

> There is an **ambiguity in the grammar** involving
>   expression-statements and declarations: An expression-statement with a
>   function-style explicit type conversion as its leftmost subexpression
>   can be indistinguishable from a declaration where the first declarator
>   starts with a (. In those cases the statement is a declaration.

That is, this paragraph states how ambiguities in the grammar should be treated. There are several other ambiguities mentioned in the C++ Standard, but only three that I know are ambiguities related to the grammar, [stmt.ambig], [[dcl.ambig.res]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.ambig.res#1), a **direct consequence** of [stmt.ambig] and [[expr.unary.op]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.unary#op-10), which explicitly states the term **ambiguity in the grammar**.

[[stmt.ambig]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ambig#3):

> The disambiguation is purely syntactic; that is, the meaning of the
>   names occurring in such a statement, beyond whether they are
>   type-names or not, is not generally used in or changed by the
>   disambiguation. Class templates are instantiated as necessary to
>   determine if a qualified name is a type-name. **Disambiguation
>   precedes parsing**, and a statement disambiguated as a declaration may
>   be an ill-formed declaration. If, during parsing, a name in a template
>   parameter is bound differently than it would be bound during a trial
>   parse, the program is ill-formed. No diagnostic is required. [ Note:
>   This can occur only when the name is declared earlier in the
>   declaration. — end note ]

Well, if disambiguation precedes parsing there is nothing that could prevent a decent compiler to optimize parsing by just considering that the alternatives present in each definition of the grammar are indeed ordered. With that in mind, the first sentence in [lex.ext]/1 below could be eliminated.

[[lex.ext]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.ext#1):

> If a token matches both user-defined-literal and another literal kind,
>   it is treated as the latter. [ Example: 123_­km is a
>   user-defined-literal, but 12LL is an integer-literal. — end example ]
>   The syntactic non-terminal preceding the ud-suffix in a
>   user-defined-literal is taken to be the longest sequence of characters
>   that could match that non-terminal.

<s>Note also that this paragraph doesn't mention **ambiguity in the grammar**, which for me at least, is an indication that the ambiguity doesn't exist.</s>

Comment: How could user-defined-literal work otherwise? They look just like literals of other kinds except for a suffix.

Comment: There is no order, it's just a list of grammars.  If there was an order, it would be defined in the paragraphs of the section

Comment: @NicolBolas 12LL [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ext#1.example-1) could be both, an integer-literal and a user-defined-literal.

Comment: @Belloc: That doesn't affect what I said. If the parser was not greedy, then it wouldn't be able to parse *any* UDLs.

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, 123_km could be a user-defined-literal, but is not an integer-literal.

Comment: @Belloc: But 123 could be in integer-literal or not, depending on what characters follow.

Comment: It should also be noted that your example has nothing to do with the gammar; it's the [tokenizer](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex) that determines how the sequence "123_km" gets parsed. That text is parsed as a single token, and that particular token cannot match the integer-literal grammar rule.

Comment: @NicolBolas In response to your comment " But 123 could be in integer-literal or not, depending on what characters follow.", take a look at [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ext#1.sentence-3).

Comment: @NathanOliver Could you give an example where this order is stated for some paragraph in the standard?

Comment: @Belloc: "*Could you give an example where this order is stated for some paragraph in the standard?*" He said that there was no order, because if there was, then the standard would define an order. You can't point to something that doesn't exist.

Comment: `123` can be either an integer literal or the *beginning* of a user defined literal or a floating point literal. There is no ambiguity. `123` by itself (separated as required from any following token) can only be an integer literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no implicit ordering of productions in the C++ presentation grammar.

There are ambiguities in that grammar, which are dealt with on a case-by-case basis by text in the standard. Note that the text of the the standard is *normative*; the grammar does not stand alone, and it does not override the text. The two need to be read together.

The standard itself points out that the grammar as resumed in Appendix A:

> … is not an exact statement of the language. In particular, the grammar described here accepts a superset of valid C++ constructs. Disambiguation rules (8.9, 9.2, 11.8) must be applied to distinguish expressions from declarations. Further, access control, ambiguity, and type rules must be used to weed out syntactically valid but meaningless constructs. (Appendix A, paragraph 1)

That's not a complete list of the ambiguities resolved in the text of the standard, because there are also rules about lexical ambiguities. (See below.)

Almost all of these ambiguity resolution clauses are of the form "if both *P* and *Q* applies, choose *Q*", and thus would be unnecessary were there an implicit ordering of grammar alternatives, since the correct parse could be guaranteed simply by putting the alternatives in the correct order. So the fact that the standard feels the need to dedicate a number of clauses to ambiguity resolution is *prima facie* evidence that alternatives are not implicitly ordered. [Note 1]

The C++ standard does not explicitly name the grammar formalism being used, but it does credit the antecedents which allows us to construct a historical argument. The formalism used by the C++ standard was inherited from the C standard and the description in Kernighan & Ritchie's original book on the (then newly-minted) C language. K&R wrote their grammar using the Yacc parser generator, and the original C grammar is basically a Yacc grammar file. Yacc uses the LALR(1) algorithm to construct a parser from a context-free grammar (CFG), and its grammar files are a concrete representation of that grammar written in what has come to be known as BNF (although there is some historical ambiguity about what the letters in BNF actually stand for). BNF does not have any implicit ordering of rules, and the formalism does not allow any way to write an explicit ordering or any other disambiguation rule. (A BNF grammar must be unambiguous in order to be mechanically parsed; if it is ambiguous, the LALR(1) algorithm will fail to generate a parser.)

Yacc does go a bit outside of the box. It has some automatic disambiguation rules, and one mechanism to provide explicit disambiguation (operator precedence). But Yacc's disambiguation has nothing to do with the ordering of alternatives either.

In short, ordered alternatives were not really a feature of any grammar formalism until 2002 when Bryan Ford proposed packrat parsing, and subsequently formalised a class of grammars which he called "Parsing Expression Grammars" (PEGs). The PEG algorithm does implicitly order alternatives, by insisting that the right-hand alternative in an alternation only be attempted if the left-hand alternative failed to match. For this reason, the PEG alternation operator (or "ordered alternation" operator) is generally written as `/` instead of `|`, avoiding confusion with the traditional unordered alternation syntax.

A key feature of the PEG algorithm is that it is *always deterministic*. Every PEG grammar can be deterministically applied to a source text without ambiguity. (That doesn't mean that the grammar will give you the parse you wanted, of course. It just means that it will never give you a list of parses and let you select the one you want.) So grammars written in PEG cannot be accompanied by textual rules which disambiguate, because there are no ambiguities.

I mention this because the existence and popularity of PEG have to some extent altered the perception of the meaning of the alternation operator. Before PEG, we probably wouldn't be having this kind of discussion at all. But using PEG as a guide to interpreting the C++ grammar formalism is ahistoric and unjustifiable; the roots of the C++ grammar go back to at least 1978, at least a quarter of a century before PEG.

#### Lexical ambiguities, and the clauses which resolve them

1. `[lex.pptoken]` (§5.4) paragraph 3 lays down the fundamental rules for token recognition, which is a little more complicated than the traditional "maximal munch" principle which always recognises the longest possible token starting immediately after the previously recognised token. It includes two exceptions:

   - The sequence `<::` is treated as starting with the token `<` rather than the longer token `<:` unless it is the start of `<::>` (treated as `<:`, `:>`) or `<:::` (treated as `<:`, `::`). That might all make more sense if you mentally replace `<:` with `[` and `:>` with `]`, which is the intended syntactic equivalence.
   - A raw string literal is terminated by the *first* matching delimiter sequence. This rule could in theory be written in a context-free grammar only because there is an explicit limit on the length of termination sequences, which means that the theoretical CFG would have on the order of 88<sup>16</sup> rules, one for each possible delimiter sequence. In practice, this rule cannot be written as such, and it is described textually, along with the 16-character limit on the length of the *d-char-sequence*.
2. `[lex-header]` (§5.8) avoids the ambiguity between *header-names* and *string-literals* (as well as certain token sequences starting with `<`) by requiring *header-name* to only be recognised in certain contexts, including an `#include` preprocessing directive. (The section does not actually say that the *string-literal* should not be recognised, but I think that the implication is clear.)
3. `[lex.ext]` (§5.13.8) paragraph 1 resolves the ambiguities involved with *user-defined-literals*, by requiring that:

   - the *user-defined-literal* rule is only recognised if the token cannot be recognised as some other kind of literal, and
   - the decomposition of the *user-defined-literal* into a literal followed by a *ud-suffix* follows the longest-token rule, described above.

   Note that this rule is not really a tokenisation rule, because it is applied *after* the source text has been divided into tokens. Tokenisation is done in translation phase 3, after which the tokens are passed through the preprocessing directives (phase 4), rewriting of escape sequences and UCNs (phase 5), and concatenation of string literals (phase 6). Each token which emerges from phase 6 must then be reinterpreted as a token in the syntactic grammar, and it is at that point that literal tokens will be classified. So it's not necessary that §5.13.8 clarify what the extent of the token being categorised is; the extent is already known and the converted token must use exactly all of the characters in the preprocessing token. Thus it's quite different from the other ambiguities in this list, but I left it here because it is so present in the original question and in the various comment threads.

#### Notes:

1. Curiously, in almost all of the ambiguity resolution clauses, the preferred alternative is the one which appears later in the list of alternatives. For example, §8.9 explicitly prefers *declarations* to *expressions*, but the grammar for *statement* lists *expression-statement* long before *declaration-statement*. Having said that, correctly parsing C++ requires a more sophisticated algorithm than just "try to parse a declaration and if that fails, then try to parse as an expression," because there are programs which must be parsed as a declaration with a syntax error (see the example at [stmt.ambig]/3).

Comment: See my **Edit** above

Comment: @Belloc: The words "matches both" and "ambiguity" mean the same thing. ("Ambiguous" and "both" both derive from ambo(s), which is still the way you say it in Spanish and I think in Portuguese as well.) Anyway, the word "ambiguity" is definitely used in the other clauses I cited, in situations which could equally have been disambiguated by a implicit ordering, BTW, did you read my answer; specifically the part where I mention that the case of *user-defined-literals* is actually neither in the tokenisation nor the syntax, but in the conversion of preprocessing tokens to tokens?

Comment: "Anyway, the word "ambiguity" is definitely used in the other clauses I cited, in situations **which could equally have been disambiguated by a implicit ordering**". That's what I don't understand. you **only** need a **non**-implicit ordering when there is an ambiguity. Otherwise, i.e., without ambiguities (99.99% of the time) you can use the syntax trees assuming an implicit ordering and it will work. Do you agree with that or not?

Comment: @belloc: without ambiguities, you can consider the possibilities in *whatever order you like* because you know only one will match and so when you find a match, you can stop searching. If the parser is constrained by an implicit order, it can also stop when it finds a match, but it might end up wasting time on unlikely productions because they were earlier in the list. Because there is no implicit order, the parser is free to try alternatives in the order it deems most efficient, except in the cases where the standard provides an *explicit* ordering to resolve ambiguity....

Comment: Many languages (which are not ambiguous) can be parsed by deterministic parsers which do not depend on order at all but rather go immediately to the only possible production (or set of productions which can be explored in parallel). Grammars which rely on ordering, whether explicit or implicit -- and that is only a difference in presentation -- cannot use this approach without provision for exceptions (since most of the time, the decision is deterministic even in ambiguous grammars). But that's an implementation detail.

Comment: @belloc: so it's not that I disagree with your statement. It's that I find it irrelevant. In the absence of ambiguity, you can use what you consider an implicit order if you like, but the grammar has no need of any ordering because only one alternative can possibly match. That's the definition of unambiguous. If there is ambiguity, you can either rely on implicit ordering, as in PEG, or on explicit ambiguity resolution statements, as in the C++ standard. So if implicit ordering never needs to be used to find a correct parse, it's not relevant to the language definition.

Comment: I'm giving up. I'm really thankful for your attention, but your explanations didn't convince me.

Comment: After reading and rereading your answer very carefully, I'm finally convinced that it  was correct, i.e., that there is no implicit ordering of productions in the C++ grammar. Thus, I want to thank you for your time and patience, in answering my question.

Comment: @Belloc: Cool. I should have said earlier that I did actually appreciate the discussion because it forced me to read some sections of the standard much more closely than I had before. In particular, [stmt.ambig]/3 is a fascinating detail I had previously overlooked. So thanks for that.

Comment: I have something to tell you. But it will be better if we talk about this on a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216061/recollections).

Comment: You wrote above: " (A BNF grammar must be unambiguous in order to be mechanically parsed; if it is ambiguous, the LALR(1) algorithm will fail to generate a parser.)". That seems to be in contradiction with the first statement [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar). Continuing ...

Comment: But I believe you're right. Could you please confirm this?

Comment: @belloc: there are bnf grammars for which the LALR(1) algorithm does not produce a parser, either because the grammar is ambiguous or because it requires lookahead of more than one. I don't see any contradiction between that statement and the wikipedia article. What we can say (and I think Wikipedia does say) is that if a language (not a grammar) is deterministic, then an LALR(1) grammar exists. (Not that every grammar for that language is LALR(1), which is not true.) But not all languages are deterministic and some have no unambiguous grammars...

Comment: In practical terms, a non-deterministic or inherently ambiguous language may not be the optimal choice for programming computers. Although some Perl programmers would disagree :-)

Comment: According to this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) in Wikipedia, my interpretation is that a CFG *cannot* be an ambiguous grammar. But the previously [cited article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar) says in its first sentence: "In computer science, an ambiguous grammar is a context-free grammar ...". What am I missing?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Grammar_ambiguity

Comment: Why do you believe that article says a CFG cannot be ambiguous?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218537/discussion-between-rici-and-belloc).

Answer (score 1):

No ordering is either implied or necessary.

<strike>All seven kinds of literal are distinct.  No token that meets the definition of any of them can meet the definition of any other.</strike> For example, `42` is an *integer-literal* and cannot be a *floating-point-literal*.

How a compiler determines what a token is is an implementation detail that the standard doesn't address, and doesn't need to.

If there were an ambiguity, so that for example the same token could be either an *integer-literal* or a *user-defined-literal*, either the language would have to have a rule to disambiguate it, or it would be a bug in the grammar.

UPDATE: There is in fact such an ambiguity. As discussed in comments, `42ULL` satisfies the syntax of either an *integer-literal* or a *user-defined-literal*. This ambiguity is resolved, not by the ordering of the grammar productions, but by an explicit statement:

> If a token matches both *user-defined-literal* and another *literal* kind, it is treated as the latter.

Comment: "No ordering is either implied or necessary" - Is there any quote in the Standard supporting this?

Comment: "No token that meets the definition of any of them can meet the definition of any other." That is not correct. As I mentioned in one of my comments above 12LL can be both, an integer-literal and a user-defined-literal.

Comment: @Belloc: "*Is there any quote in the Standard supporting this*" You can't quote the non-existence of a statement. I mean, you can point to where it would probably appear if there was a statement about ordering, but that's not something you can point to.

Comment: @Belloc: The standard does say this: "If a token matches both *user-defined-literal* and another literal kind, it is treated as the latter." `[lex.ext]`/1. That is a rule for disambiguating. Whether you consider that an "ordering" or not will depend on how you use the word "ordering", but the C++ standard consistently phrases disambiguating rules by specifying which interpretation should be used (see, for example, `[stmt.ambig]` and `[dcl.ambig.res]`; that's not a complete list.)

Comment: @rici Finally somebody came to point to the sentence ("If a token matches both user-defined-literal and another literal kind, it is treated as the latter.") that I think was **not** necessary, based on my previous belief that the parser would just stop in the *integer-literal* if the token was found to match this definition.(to be continued)

Comment: @rici  I remember someone from SO supporting a claim similar to the one I'm espousing now, i.e., that as soon the parser matches a token with a definition in the grammar it stopped the parsing. That's why I am being so adamant about this. But unfortunately, I can't remember the person's name who posted this, as an issue in GitHub, although in that case he was referring to a different grammar production.

Comment: @Belloc: If the alternatives were processed as though the grammar were a PEG, then *user-defined-literal* would have to come **first**; otherwise, it could never be recognised. But the C++ grammar is not a PEG; it's an ambiguous CFG and the disambiguation rules are to be found in the text, as noted at the top of Appendix A ("This summary... is not an exact statement of the language... Disambiguation rules must be applied..."). Anyway, it's easy to find incorrect claims being espoused on SO. I'm possibly guilty of that myself, since I've made lots of claims despite being a human :-)

Comment: @Belloc: Note that a PEG is *never* ambiguous, because alternatives are ordered. So the fact that the standard says that certain parts of the grammar are ambiguous is *prima facie* evidence that the grammar is not a PEG. If it would help, I could shift this from comments to an answer, but I don't know that it would add anything.

Comment: @rici "If the alternatives were processed as though the grammar were a PEG, then user-defined-literal would have to come first; otherwise, it could never be recognised." That is not correct because of this [sentence](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ext#1.sentence-3).

Comment: @Belloc: But in PEG rules, there are never two possible alternative matches, so it doesn't make any sense to talk about the longest possible sequence. The ordering of alternatives precludes any ambiguity, and that means that if every derivation of *Q* has a derivation of *P* as a prefix, then you must write `Q / P` because `P / Q` would make *Q* useless. (This also applies to the ordering of *long-suffix* and *long-long-suffix* in the *integer-suffix* rules, among many others.)

Comment: @Belloc: Anyway, the hypothesis that the C++ grammar is a PEG is ahistoric. PEGs were invented by Bryan Ford in the first years of this century; the C++ standard is the lineal descendent of a document which is much older than that.

Comment: @rici To tell you the truth, I don't really know what you meant by PEG. What I was trying to say was that 123_km will always be identified as a user-defined-literal just by using by the [sentence](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ext#1.sentence-3) I mentioned above, without the need of the first sentence in this paragraph, if we assume of course, that the parser stops the parsing at the definition that matches the token being parsed.

Comment: @rici But I'll try to locate the issue in GitHub that I mentioned earlier, in which the OP justified his thought with a claim similar to the one we are discussing now.

Comment: @Belloc: [Parsing Expression Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar). Before PEGs started to be popular, there was no grammar formalism in use where alternatives were ordered. (And that's why PEG uses `/` instead of `|` as the alternation operator, although not all implementations which have followed have respected that convention. Which makes for confusion, IMHO.)

Comment: @Belloc, anyway that sentence doesn't help you with all the other ambiguities in the C++ grammar, so arguing about this one case is a bit futile.

Comment: @rici Of course it does not help for the other ambiguities, as these other ambiguities necessarily must have their own disambiguation statements.

Comment: @Belloc: Precisely my point. The fact that disambiguation statements are necessary is clear evidence that there is no implicit ordering of productions, because if there were an implicit ordering it would not be necessary to override it with disambiguation statements. (Most but not all of the disambiguation statements prefer later alternatives, for what it's worth.)

Answer (score 0):

The [section on syntactic notation](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/syntax) in the standard only says this about what it means:

> In the syntax notation used in this document, syntactic categories are indicated by *italic* type, and literal words and characters in `constant width` type. Alternatives are listed on separate lines except in a few cases where a long set of alternatives is marked by the phrase “one of”. If the text of an alternative is too long to fit on a line, the text is continued on subsequent lines indented from the first one. An optional terminal or non-terminal symbol is indicated by the subscript “<sub>opt</sub>”, so
>
> { expression<sub>opt</sub> }
>
> indicates an optional expression enclosed in braces.

Note that the statement considers the terms in grammars to be "alternatives", rather than a list or even an ordered list. There is no statement about ordering of the "alternatives" at all.

As such, this strongly suggests that there is no ordering at all.

Indeed, the presence throughout the standard of specific rules to disambiguate cases where multiple terms match also suggests that the alternatives are not written as a prioritized list. If the alternatives were some kind of ordered list, [this statement would be redundant](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ext#1):

> If a token matches both *user-defined-literal* and another *literal* kind, it is treated as the latter.

Comment: "As such, this strongly suggests that there is no ordering at all." Well, I don't agree with the "strongly". This issue is so important that it should be present in the standard on its own, perhaps with capital letters!!

Comment: @Belloc: It's only important if you expect there to be an order. If you just read the specification and expect only what it actually says, it's fine.

Comment: I'll try to find the issue in GitHub that I referred to in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62181836/is-it-correct-to-say-that-there-is-no-implied-ordering-in-the-presentation-of-gr#comment109979328_62182827) above.